# Smallest values are invisible in ng2-charts bar charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

[Please find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMsmT.jpg)

As you can see in the image. The second value is 1 and the highest value is around 160 hence the bar with value 1 is not visible to the user. If the highest values are even more bigger then all the smallest values are stuck at zero position, those are only visible when you hover over it and then it shows the black label, i also checked the options avaliable for barchart but couldnt find anything relavant. Is there any way to show them slighiglty above the zero position so that they are visible and bar chart doest seems to be empty

Answer (score 0):

No, this would totally go against the priciple of plotting the chart because then the chart doesnt represent the data correctly anymore. What you can do is bind the dataset with low values to a second Y axis so they go up high. But in this case it is a distorted image which is hard to compare bars with eachother.

If you really want it to show the only way is to adjust the value of it but then it is flawed data since you dont know if it is a true value or faked one that needs to be semi high to show